# Mui Modal closing on Dispatching action in the Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a modal component that opens onClick. This component uses a callback from it's parent component that dispatches an action from it's parent component.
The modal has a state variable called "open" which is used to decide whether to open the modal or not.

```
const handleOpen = () => {
props.getDetails(props.dsaId?props.dsaId:props.triggerName)
setOpen(open)
```

};

The handleOpen function is called when the button is clicked.
As you can see setOpen changes [open] value  to true , which in turn should open the Modal.

```
    props.getDetails(props.dsaId?props.dsaId:props.triggerName)
```

is used for dispatching an action in the parent component, which in turn will pass the data as props to my child component.

The problem is when i call the callback function from the child component, action dispatched in the parent component causes the parent to rerender , which in turn re-renders the child component setting [open] to false again, which closes the modal.

How do i Keep the modal open , after dispatching the action.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep modal's open state in parent component and pass it in the props to the child component.

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [childModalOpen, setChildModalOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <Child
            modalOpen={childModalOpen}
            onModalChange={(open) => setChildModalOpen(open)}                                                         
            {...otherProps}
         />);
};
const Child = ({ modalOpen, onModalChange }) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(modalOpen);

    useEffect(() => {
        setOpen(modalOpen);
    }, [modalOpen]);

    const handleOpen = () => {
        onModalChange(true);
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
        onModalChange(close);
    };

    return (
        <Modal open={} onClose={handleClose}>
            {* children *}
        </Modal>);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the state of the model up to the parent state. [Read[Lifting up the state]](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: Even if I lift the state up. The parent component would still rerender when an action is dispatched from it. Hence after rerender the state variable will be set to null again. And so the  modal will close again

Comment: Can you post sandbox link or some reference to the code? Another Solution that is coming to the top of my mind is to create one more parent component and put your existing components as children and dispatch actions from them. And maintain state in the new component.